How does Pashalik Mons deal damage when it dies?
The card Pashalik Mons states that when it (or another Goblin you control) dies, it deals damage. (It being Pashalik Mons.)
The question has arisen in our group: if Pashalik Mons is dead, how is it dealing damage? Is it a creature source of damage? As far as we are aware, if a creature dies with its ability on the stack, the ability usually fizzles.
How does this work?

The existence of Mogg Fanatic kind of hints this is supposed to work

The main rules that allow this are 113.7 and 113.7a:

113.7 The source of an ability is the object that generated it. The source of an activated ability on the stack is the object whose ability was activated. The source of a triggered ability (other than a delayed triggered ability) on the stack, or one that has triggered and is waiting to be put on the stack, is the object whose ability triggered. To determine the source of a delayed triggered ability, see rules 603.7d-f.

113.7a. Once activated or triggered, an ability exists on the stack independently of its source. Destruction or removal of the source after that time won't affect the ability. Note that some abilities cause a source to do something (for example, "Prodigal Pyromancer deals 1 damage to any target") rather than the ability doing anything directly. In these cases, any activated or triggered ability that references information about the source for use while announcing an activated ability or putting a triggered ability on the stack checks that information when the ability is put onto the stack. Otherwise, it will check that information when it resolves. In both instances, if the source is no longer in the zone it's expected to be in at that time, its last known information is used. The source can still perform the action even though it no longer exists.


"Last known information", as defined in the glossary, is

Information about an object that's no longer in the zone it's expected to be in, or information about a player who's no longer in the game. This information captures that object's last existence in that zone or that player's last existence in the game. See rules 113.7a, 608.2b, 608.2h, and 800.4h.

In short, when Pashalik Mons dies and its triggered ability resolves, the damage is dealt by the creature Palashik Mons was right before it died.

In addition, you said

This seems extra strange as, at least to our knowledge, if a creature dies with its ability on the stack, the ability usually fizzles.

but as you can see, rule 113.7a says the opposite. Removing a creature with its ability on the generally does not fizzle the ability, though of course abilities that only affect their source have nothing to do if the source is no longer there.

Absolutely fantastic, thank you! I suspected we had that wrong.

One caveat to the final sentence: If the ability on the stack in some way requires the creature to still be on the battlefield (most commonly if it’s doing something to the creature itself, such as putting counters on it), then it will in fact fizzle if you remove the creature from the battlefield before it can resolve, though it only does so when it tries to resolve. This case may be what confused the OP, since in my experience it’s much more common in some play groups than the type of situation the question was asking about.

In the situation you're describing, the ability doesn't actually fizzle, in the sense that it isn't removed from the stack; it does resolve completely and it just doesn't do whatever it would do to to creature that is no longer there. That does make a difference if the ability also does something else. For example, if you activate Sphinx of Magosi's ability and it dies before the ability resolves, nothing gets a counter but you still draw a card.

But if it's a targeting ability/spell that loses all of its targets... Though I don't think there are abilities on permanents that target the permanent itself (and how would that even be phrased?)

Yes, that is what causes an ability to fizzle. But the purpose of "target" in a spell or ability is to be able to choose from potentially multiple options. An ability that is predefined to target one specific object is the opposite of that, so it just wouldn't make sense.

@ilkkachu not specifically, but there are a lot of examples of abilities on creatures that can target a creature and don't exclude itself by saying 'another' though granted most of these aren't useful for the creature that has them, often tapping creatures or being power and toughness related with a tap cost.
